# XSLT version 1.0, 'Select' then 'Store' into an Array then 'Sort' Array and Display Array

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I am a new to XSLT world. I was just wondering how Can I save my select result into an Array and sort that Array and then pick up my desirable index of array and display. After googling a bit about the problem I am able to use sort on a field. But I do not want to play inside with XML as it will be pretty long and complex rather I will prefer storing the result and then play around.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
                <date>2023-01-01</date>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
                <date>2022-01-01</date>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
                <date>2021-01-01</date>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <xsl:sort select="date"/>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So How can I collect all dates at one place and then sort them. Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. There are no arrays as such in XML/XSLT. If you like, you can define a variable to "store" all your dates as `<xsl:variable name="dates" select="catalog/cd/date" />`. Though all this stores is a reference to the original nodes. You can also define a variable to contain a *copy* of the original nodes, e.g. after sorting.

Comment: I tried <xsl:variable name="dates" select="catalog/cd/date" /> but this only gives me one date 2023-01-01 instead of all dates

Comment: No, it has all the dates (provided you do this from the context of `/`). But if you're testing the contents by `xsl:value-of`, you will only get the first one (in XSLT 1.0).